# passing variables as parameter from JSP in onChange event?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I'd like to know if it is possible to pass variables as a parameter from JSP to `Onchange` function. If so, how to do it ?

```
<%>for(int i = 0; i < i < 100; i ++){<%>
    <select name="<%= i %>user" id="<%= i %>" onchange="myFunction(<%=i%>)">
      <option value="present">present</option>
      <option value="absent">absent</option>
      <option value="holiday">holiday</option>
    </select>
<%>}<%>
```

```
function myFunction(i) {
    var element = document.getElementById(i);

    element.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
}
```

I've been trying different ways, but it doesn't work.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<c:forEach></<c:forEach>` loop to iterate and use `${loop.index}` to get particular value i.e : `0,1..100`

Your **jsp** code will look like below :

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 //begin from 0 loop till 100 
 <c:forEach begin="0" end="100" varStatus="loop">
       <select name="${loop.index}user" id="${loop.index}" onchange="myFunction(${loop.index})">
            <option value="present">present</option>
            <option value="absent">absent</option>
            <option value="holiday">holiday</option>
       </select>
  </c:forEach>
```

Your **javascript** code :

```
function myFunction(i) {
   var element = document.getElementById(i);//getting id
    element.style.background = "blue";//apply bg color 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have never used JSTL before, but it was a really good practice!